# Remove a word using CSS

Tags: css

I have a Wordpress site and I have like to remove the word 'Author:' from 'Author: darylwong'

The final output should be only darylwong without Author.  The CSS is like below:

```
<h1 class='site-title loop-title'
  itemprop='headline'>
  Author: 
  <span class='vcard'>darylwong</span>
</h1>
```

I have tried something like:

```
.site-title, not(.vcard) {
  display: none;
}
```

But it is still showing 'Author: darylwong' instead of only 'darylwong'.

Could someone help me to take a look?

The jsfiddle is here at https://jsfiddle.net/mwf400n3/

Comment: And... `.site-title *:not(.vcard)`? The operator is `:not` (included `:`).

Comment: Note that Alejandro also removed the comma. The comma denotes 2 separate selectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply a negative text-indent on the `.site-title` div and then apply a positive text-indent to the target `.vcard` span, also change the display property.

```
.site-title {
  text-indent:-9999px;
}
.vcard {
  text-indent: 9999px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

http://codepen.io/partypete25/pen/MyqZmm

Note: this is working under the assumption that you can't edit/modify the html? Otherwise you should look into a) removing the word altogether or b)wrapping the word in a span and then hiding that.

Comment: .site-title.loop-title {
 text-indent: -9999px;
   }

   .vcard {
 text-indent: 9999px;
 display: inline-block;
}

Comment: @DarylWong Just because the element has two classes doesn't mean you have to specify both in your css. It does add the the specificity of your css declaration though.

Comment: It also makes the selector more unique as it will only target elements that have both classes. It's up to you to decide which works best in this instance. you might also want to add that to your .vcard selector as well so that it only comes into effect when .vcard exists within .site-title.loop-title. eg; .site-title.loop-title .vcard { text-indent: 9999px; display: inline-block; }

Answer (score 1):

Why not wrap Author with a span and style that to display none.

Answer (score 0):

```
.site-title {visibility: hidden;position:relative;}
.vcard {
  visibility: visible;
  position:absolute;
  left:0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@partypete25, yes, that works.

```
.site-title.loop-title {
   text-indent: -9999px;
 }

.vcard {
   text-indent: 9999px;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mwf400n3/