# Remove the word 'views' from YouTube

Tags: html, view, youtube, character

I'm making a YouTube Tweaks theme for Stylish using CSS, I've changed some icons and some colors, but I was wondering if there's a way to remove the word 'views' from the viewcounter (using only CSS). I can't modify the original line since it changes in every video, but I can add more code lines using the extension.

This is the line:

```
<div class="watch-view-count">1,234,567 views</div>
```

**TL;DR:** I want to remove the last word of a div, or the last 5 characters using CSS.
[Image reference of how I wish it would look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtUit.png)

Comment: probably not possible with just css.  Pretty easy to do with just a little javascript, will that work for you?

Comment: @DCR Stylish doesn't let you use javascript, but I just found an extension called js-injector that let's me inject javascript, do you know where I should start looking to accomplish what I'm looking for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove a word using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36878447/remove-a-word-using-css)

Comment: I only have 1 class, I can't use that method since I have multiple words in one single class. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var view = document.getElementById('watch-view-count');
var html = view.innerHTML;
var words = html.split(" ");
var length = words.length;

var newHTML="";

for(let i = 0; i < length - 1; i++){
   newHTML += words[i];
}
view.innerHTML = newHTML;
```

```html
<div id="watch-view-count">1,234,567 views</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! It does what I asked! For some reason I can't manage to make it run with JS Injector or Greasemonkey, but that problem is on my end I guess. Thank you anyways! Do you know any program that let's you inject javascript into pages?

Comment: tell me more about your operating environment.  Are you using wordpress?

Comment: I'm using a browser extension called Stylish to modify the css of YouTube, and I tried to add the code you sent using Greasemonkey but it didn't work, I tried Tampermonkey and it didn't work either.

Comment: Here you can find what I've done so far https://userstyles.org/styles/180914/classic-youtube-tweaks